# Why is this error not ending up in my Redux Action's Catch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, async-await

In this app, I'm using async await to try handle an API call through a couple of functions. As I'm testing the sad path error routing, I'm noticing that the error does not end up in the `catch`.

**The Action which starts the whole process**

```
export const submitBasicDetails = form => async dispatch => {
    try {
        const response = await interstitialHandlerPromise(Actions.SUBMIT_FORM, form); // <- we end up here
        console.log('submitBasicDetails response', response); // <-- we see the error here
        const {id} = response.data;

        dispatch({
            type: Actions.SUBMIT_FORM,
            id
        });

        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('ACTION', error); // <-- instead of here :()
        dispatch({
            type: Actions.SUBMIT_FORM_FAIL,
            id: null,
            error: 'There was a server error, please try again later.'
        });
    }
};
```

The form data then hits this `interstitialHandlerPromise` where we decide which API method to use:

```
export const interstitialHandlerPromise = (type, data) => {
    const {requestMethod, config} = determineRequestMethod(type);

    const requests = requestMethod(data);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        interstitialHandler(requests, config)
            .then(response => resolve(response))
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('intersitial error', error);
                reject(error);
            })
    );
};
```

Finally the `postForm` function which is `requests` that is inside of the function above:

```
// /test will cause a 500 error since it doesn't exist
export const postForm = async (form, END_POINT = '/api/test') => {
    const resPayload = form.data;
    const resUrl = `${BASE_URL}${V1}${END_POINT}`;

    try {
        const res = await axios.post(resUrl, {...resPayload});

        return {
            res
        };
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('postForm e', e); // <-- This hits because `/test` returns 500
        return new Error(e.message);
    }
};
```

Comment: `postForm` is a promise and is catching the error, so it just returns the whatever the catch is returning

Comment: `postForm` does `return` an error instead of `throw`ing it

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it) in `interstitialHandlerPromise`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Instead of returning the error, I needed to **throw** the error.

In the postForm function:

```
} catch (e) {
    console.log('postInitialLoss e', e);
    throw new Error(e.message);
}
```

Then in the `intersitialHandlerPromise`:

```
export const interstitialHandlerPromise = async (type, data) => {
    const {requestMethod, config} = determineRequestMethod(type);

    const requests = requestMethod(data);

    try {
        const response = await interstitialHandler(requests, config);
        return response;
    } catch(e) {
        throw new Error(e); // <- this gets hit
    }
};
```

Now finally back in the action we will end up in the `catch`:

```
} catch (error) {
    console.log('ACTION (SHOULD GET HERE)!', error); // <-- WE are here! :D
    dispatch({
        type: Actions.SUBMIT_BASIC_DETAILS_FAIL,
        initialLossCreated: false,
        error: 'There was a server error, please try again later.'
    });
}
```

Comment: If all you do is re`throw`ing the error, you just should drop the `try`/`catch` block and let the exception propagate normally.

Comment: @Bergi that is true!